# Template not displaying in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following code in my initial project

**mytools.hbs**

```
<div class="section">
    {{view Mytest.MyformView contentBinding="model"}}
</div>
```

**routes.js**

```
Mytest.MyformRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
       return [{defaultvalues:''}]; 
    }
});
```

**views.js**

```
Mytest.MyformView = Ember.View.extend({
    isShowVisible: true,
    templateName: Ember.TEMPLATES['myform'],
    actions: {
        ShowDefaultValues: function(){
            this.toggleProperty('isShowVisible');
        }
    }
});
```

**myform.hbs**

```
{{#if view.isShowVisible}}
    Name  : <font color='blue'>{{view.content.Name}}</font>
    Email : <font color='blue'>{{view.content.Email}}</font>
    <button {{action "ShowDefaultValues" target="view"}}>Edit</button>

{{else}}
    Name  : {{input type="text" value=view.content.Name}}
    Email : {{input type="text" value=view.content.Email}}
    <button {{action "ShowDefaultValues" target="view"}}>Done</button>
{{/if}}
```

With the above script, the template `myform.hbs` is not displaying.
I am not getting any error in console.

What is wrong with my above code?

I need the views, routes and handlebars in separate files but not in same HTML file under *script* tag.

I have referred many Q & A in stackoverflow and other sites as well but I could not able to find solution.

**EDIT 1:** I am using ember 1.2.1

**EDIT 2:** Is there any work around to convert the above script to latest version?

Comment: What version of Ember are you using?

Comment: I am using ember 1.2.1 and I am okay with this version. Because I have tried few projects with the same version and got expected results.

Comment: How do you build your app?

Comment: You are using an old and unsupported ember version - it's unlikely anyone will be able to help you with this.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to try with latest version of emberjs? If so can you please tell me the solution with latest version. Because the theme is, I need solution.

Comment: The new version of Ember works in a whole different way. I suggest you use ember-cli, see http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/

Comment: Will v1.11.0 work for me?

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use 2.4, which will also be the first LTS version, but you should at least use 1.13! And use ember-cli!

Comment: I am hard to find the way to convert the above script to the latest version of emberjs. Script for the updated version will be useful for me.